# Get certificate of XMPP S2S gateway

Tags: openssl, xmpp

I am trying to fetch certificate from XMPP s2s gateway. I have tried with openssl but getting like this on a public XMPP server "jabber.at"

```
$ openssl s_client -starttls xmpp-server  -connect xmpp.jabber.at:5269
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 319 bytes and written 119 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
---
```

I am new to XMPP / Jabber. Also included the SRV record of jabber.at

```
$ host -t srv _xmpp-server._tcp.jabber.at
_xmpp-server._tcp.jabber.at has SRV record 300 0 5269 xmpp.jabber.at.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify also `-xmpphost`*hostname*, where *hostname* is the name after @ in the jabber ID, e.g.

When your XMPP server hosts the JID `your_name@example.com` then *hostname* would be `example.com`.